# Clone a git repo with credentials using gulp-git

Tags: javascript, git, gulp

I am trying to clone a git repo from personal server via gulp-git into 'test' folder and it requires username and password. Not sure how to pass username and password. Please note its not a github repository

```
gulp.task('clone', function(){
git.clone('http://webrepo/git/mytest.git',{args:'./test'},function(err){
    if (err) throw err
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify username and password in your repo URL:

```
gulp.task('clone', function(){
  git.clone('http://username:password@webrepo/git/mytest.git',
            {args:'./test'}, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

All the usual caveats about storing clear text passwords in files and transmitting them over plain HTTP apply of course.

Comment: Using your suggestion i don't get any errors but the test directory is still empty and clone finished in 8.21ms

Comment: ok, sorted..this was wrong './test' ..it should be 'myfolder/test'  -- Thank you